# Responsive web design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html5boilerplate

After a long time i got a new project, where i'm going to implement the RWD. Before getting project i was talking a lot the RWD, but when it comes to writing the code, i see lot of confusion. I really need your suggestions and ideas for proceeding further.

Here are my questions:

1. How to support support media queries stuff to the older versions of browser(ie6 ie7 ie8 etc) or what is the alternative way to do it.
2. Do i need to use the flexible layout within the fixed main layout (like percentage based widths)
3. What about using the Boilerplate or bootstrap etc which supports for fallback version also
4. What about using modernizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend if you are stuck please look at conditionizr http://conditionizr.com/

for more information on media queries go here http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/